# Python Shell memory management for always running script

Tags: python, memory-management

I have written a python (python version is 3) script that runs 24/7. The way I run my script in my Windows machine is the following. I right click on the .py file, then click on "Edit with IDLE" and then "Run". The script has no issue but, due to the many instructions printed in the python shell (I use a logger), after a couple of days this python shell gets very heavy. My newbie question is the following. Is there to limit the number of rows temporarily saved in the python shell to a specific number? Or perhaps somebody has a better suggestion to run this constantly running script that prints a lot of the script steps in the shell? Please, notice how I'm not asking how to run a script 24/7, it's my understanding the best way to do it is though a VPS. My problem is that the data saved in the displayed python shell gets bigger and bigger every day, so I only wonder how to limit the data temporarily displayed/saved in it. Thanks

Comment: The best answer is that you should be using the logging module to save output somewhere, rather than keeping an open terminal with printed statements as the output.  Then the shell doesn't continue to consume memory and you're using the file system for storage.  Also, why are you launching it from IDLE?  Why not just `c:\path\to\python.exe myscript.py`?

Comment: *"I'm not asking how to run a script 24/7"* -- You should be. This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @g.d.d.c I also print debug level data in a log file, I was using the shell, just to keep an eye on main steps currently happening with my script. "Why not just c:\path\to\python.exe myscript.py"  apologize for my ignorant question, but is that better than running it using the idle? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because you don't have IDLE consuming memory, and the automatic console buffers would kick in for your output statements.  If you need to be able to look at and review the information while the script is running, it should go to a log.  Set up a separate logger if you want it segregated from other output of your script, but running it from IDLE "just to keep an eye on it" is terrible practice.

Comment: Got it. Ok thank you very much for your kind and precious suggestion. Happy new year!